Is there a way to `measure_memory ./program` similar to how `time ./program` measures time?
I want to be able to quickly audit how much memory a particular command/program uses.
the time command lets me measure run-time via time ./my_program . I was hoping there was a command analogous to this for memory usage.
Recommendations seem to be to use ps however that requires I know the process ID which I don't know prior to running the command/program.

Run the program in the background: ./my_program &. The PID will be printed to the terminal.

ps shows the name of the process as well.

The memory requirements will vary up and down over time, whereas time gives cumulative values. What kind of 'audit' are you after?

i am interested in knowing over the program's lifetime what is the maximum amount of memory it consumed. This is a useful metric to know in the context of competitive programming where time and space constraints exist. The space constraints occur because the VM doing automated grading just has hard limits that it errors out on if you exceed but it would be useful to be able to gauge on my own personal machine "yea this will take <10 of mb" or "oh no this will consume 10s of mb" etc...

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/gathering-information-about-memory-use

Use Ctrl+T in terminal which in BSD systems will print the process name and pid, among other things.

/usr/bin/time -l <command> will print the rusage of the process and its children.

getrusage() returns information describing the resources utilized by the current process, or all its terminated child processes.

This includes a few memory statistics such as ‘peak memory footprint’.
Note /usr/bin/time is the time binary rather than the time builtin of your shell.
